# Minimise the maximum degree of a vertex in a connected graph

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics

Given $N$ vertices and $M$ edges, how to create a connected graph so that I can minimize the maximum degree of every vertex. A vertex can have at most degree $N$ (self loop and other $N-1$ edges). Find the maximum degree of vertex in that graph. Consider all possible values of $N$ and $M$.

Comment: Perhaps you could start out by considering the extremal cases. What should you do when $M$ is as large as possible? What should you do when $M$ is as small as possible - what about if you gradually increase $M$?

Comment: @Juho I have tried the extremal cases but I failed in getting a general algorithm. If M>N*(N+1)/2 or M<N-1, Graph cannot be created according to constraints. And I had also took care of small corner cases.